# Sorting cells instead of table

Tags: swift, uitableview

My App checks which POI/ Feed/ Group the user is following. Based on that it loads comments with the content of the comment and the user name/picture. Those are loaded separately. My only issue is sorting by time.

If I use this code: `self.table = self.table.sorted(by: { $0.userTime ?? 0 > $1.userTime ?? 0 })` the sorting of the comments is correct. But the matching of the profile names and pictures is totally wrong.

If I remove that code above the matching is correct but the sorting is totally wrong. How can I solve this? Instead of sorting the table I have to sort the cell itself?

```
func loadFollowedPoi() {
    myFeed.myArray1 = []
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let database = Database.database().reference()
    database.child("user/\(userID)/abonniertePoi/").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            myFeed.myArray1.append(child.key)
        }
        self.postsLaden()
    })
}

func postsLaden() {
    dic = [:]
    
    let neueArray: [String] = []
    for groupId in myFeed.myArray1[0..<myFeed.myArray1.count] {
        
        let placeIdFromSearch = ViewController.placeidUebertragen
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("placeID/\(groupId)")
        ref.observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
            
            guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            let newPost = importPosts(dictionary: dic, key: snapshot.key)
            guard let userUid = newPost.userID else { return }

            self.fetchUser(uid: userUid, completed: {
                self.table.insert(newPost, at: 0)
                self.table = self.table.sorted(by: { $0.userTime ?? 0 > $1.userTime ?? 0 })

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
        )}
    
}


func fetchUser(uid: String, completed: @escaping () -> Void) {
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("user").child(uid).child("userInformation")
    ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        let newUser = UserModel(dictionary: dic)
        self.users.insert(newUser, at: 0)
        completed()
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        cell.post = table[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.user = users[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
}



class importPosts {
    var userID: String?
    var userGroup: String?
    var userComment: String?
    var userTime: Int?
    var userLikes: Int?
    var commentId: String?
    var placeID: String?
    var kommentarCount: Int?
    var id: String?
    
    var likeCount: Int?
    var likes: Dictionary<String, Any>?
    var isLiked: Bool?
    
    init(dictionary: [String: Any], key: String) {
        
        userID = dictionary["userID"] as? String
        userComment = dictionary["userComment"] as? String
        userGroup = dictionary["userGroup"] as? String
        userTime = dictionary["userTime"] as? Int
        userLikes = dictionary["userLikes"] as? Int
        commentId = dictionary["commentId"] as? String
        placeID = dictionary["placeID"] as? String
        kommentarCount = dictionary["kommentarCount"] as? Int
       
        id = key
        
        likeCount = dictionary["likeCount"] as? Int
        likes = dictionary["likes"] as? Dictionary<String, Any>
        
        ViewComments.commentIDNew = commentId!
        
        if let currentUserUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            if let likes = self.likes {
                isLiked = likes[currentUserUid] != nil
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Basically multiple arrays as data source is pretty bad practice. If `table` and `users` are tied to each create a new struct and zip the arrays.

Comment: I think that is not possible because username/profile picture and the comment are stored on two different places.

Comment: Obviously the arrays are related to each other so it's up to you to implement an appropriate reliable data model.

Comment: You are not really helping me right now. I would not have asked the question If I would know how to solve it.

Comment: Actually my suggestion **would** solve the problem. Sorting cells is pointless.

Comment: I don't know how to do that what you suggested

Comment: What type is `newPost`?

Comment: newpost is importPosts. I added the class importPosts above as Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments create a parent struct which contains one user an one post respectively

```
struct UserData {
    let user: UserModel
    let post: importPosts
}
```

Side note: Please name structs/classes always uppercase and why not simply `User` and `Post`?

---

Create the datasource array

```
var users = [UserData]()
```

---

Modify `fetchUser` to pass the new user in the completion handler

```
func fetchUser(uid: String, completed: @escaping (UserModel) -> Void) {
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("user").child(uid).child("userInformation")
    ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        let newUser = UserModel(dictionary: dic)
        completed(newUser)
    }
}
```

---

And modify also `postsLaden` to assign the post and the associated user to the model

```
func postsLaden() {
    //dic = [:] 
    //let neueArray: [String] = [] seems to be unused

    for groupId in myFeed.myArray1[0..<myFeed.myArray1.count] {
        
        let placeIdFromSearch = ViewController.placeidUebertragen
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("placeID/\(groupId)")
        ref.observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
            
            guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            let newPost = importPosts(dictionary: dic, key: snapshot.key)
            guard let userUid = newPost.userID else { return }

            self.fetchUser(uid: userUid, completed: { user in
                self.users.insert(UserData(user: user, post: newPost), at: 0)
                self.users.sort($0.user.userTime ?? 0 > $1.user.userTime ?? 0)    
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
        )}
    
}
```

---

Finally modify `cellForRow`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        cell.post = user.post
        cell.user = user.user
        
        return cell
}
```

Yet another side note: Sorting and reloading the table view multiple times inside the loop is unnecessarily expensive. You could add `DispatchGroup` to sort and reload the data **once** on completion. Regarding *expensive*: In the database isn't it possible that `Post` can hold a full reference to the `user` to avoid the second fetch? For example Core Data can.

Comment: Thanks for your code. Now I understood what you meant. Basically creating a main struct and loading these two data sources in this struct. And after that reading the main struct while sorting the contents of it depending on one data source in this main struct. I will also check on that suggestion with DispatchGroup. Core Data is new for me. I learned coding a few weeks ago. PS: Everything's works fine now.